# Trigger to update one field based on selection of another - two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am fairly new at Triggers as I don't use them often.
Here is my code: - Sorry i cant post it in the comments for some reason:

```
after insert, update
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @STAGE VARCHAR (50)

  set @STAGE = (SELECT b.Stage from INSERTED i inner join Opp_View B on i.Opp_Id = b.Opp_Id where i.Opp_Id = b.Opp_Id)

  if @STAGE IN ('not started','Initial comm','Needs assessment','Proposal submission','closing phase','Commitment to buy','sale won')
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO O_Stage
  (Client_id,Contact_Number,O_Stage)
  SELECT i.Opp_id, 0, b.Stage FROM INSERTED i
  inner join opp_view B on i.Opp_Id = b.Opp_Id
   where i.Opp_Type = '0' and i.Opp_Id = b.Opp_Id
   End

   End
GO
```

My results are as follows:

The results are as follows:

When i insert an opportunity, both fields have the same value. Which is good
However..
I find that if i try insert another opportunity, for the same entry - it doesnt change the valye in table 2 for example:
if i do a select * from O_stage - it only shows the first inserted record:
Client_Id | O_Stage
181004250828540240011O | Initial Comm

I need it to check if the record exists and if so Update the Stage, however if it doesnt exist (new Entry) it must insert.. The logic seems simple by doing a If Exists then update otherwise insert however i do not know how to write the syntax..

The stages are already defined in both the opportunity and the O_stage table.. Is this the wrong way to accomplish the goal? Should i leave the O_stage table blank so that when the trigger executes, it inserts the values?

How do i do the following:

check to see if a value already exists and if it does, then delete old value and insert new value

Comment: If you could add some sample data in table 1 and expected update in table2. We will look into further options of trigger update.

Comment: Why do you need to store the data twice? Is there not something that relates these two tables together (presumably there is - otherwise how do we know which rows to update?) then you can join the tables during retrieval if you just need to *show* data from both tables in a single query result.

Comment: i would prefer the data not to be stored twice. I just need the data to mirror.

Comment: i would prefer the data not to be stored twice. I just need the data to mirror. The unique identifier between the two tables is the client_id/opp_id
Data displayed as below:

OppTable:
Stage  Client_ID
Not Started 100118000940772238169O



User_fields_table
Client_id                          Typeid      Code_id         OppStage Desc
100118000940772238169O 110               2                    Not Started



When the OppStage Description is changed to a different value then the Stage must change to the same..

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I have reposted in the question section as the comment sections doesnt hold enough character